# Javascript not firing in dojox.layout.ContentPane with an Ajax form post

Tags: dojo

I have a form on my page. I want to post it and put the response in a dialog window. The response is an http page with javascript on it to execute.

I want something just like dojox.widget.DialogSimple only which works with a form post, not a regular http "get" url.

How do I use dojox.layout.ContentPane with a form post?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to post your form with xhr.post() and update the dojox.layout.ContentPane with `yourContentPane.set("content", resultOfPost)`. I'm not sure if javascript will be executed when setting the content manually or if this only works with setting the href.

Buy anyway it's not recommended to embed javascript in your html response. You can execute your code after a successful post. This pseudo code can give you an idea:

```
// Handle the submission of the "Generate service" form
on(document.body, "#yourForm:submit", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    xhr.post({
        handleAs: "text",
        form: "yourFormId",
        timeout: 15000,
        load: function(data, ioArgs) {
            var yourContentPane = registry.byId("yourContentPane");
            yourContentPane.set("content", data);
            // Execute your javascript code here, instead
            // of embedding it in the html that is loaded into
            // the content pane...
        },
        error: function(err, ioArgs) {
            // handle error
        }
    };
}));
```

In this case, the content pane also can be a simple dijit.layout.ContentPane instance, since there is no need to that embedded javascript is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that's not a bad way to do it but I was hoping for something that runs the javascript and is a bit more seamless. After much experimentation, I found this:

```
    dialog = new dojox.widget.DialogSimple({
        title: 'My Dialog',
        width: '400px',
        height: '300px',
        ioMethod: dojo.xhrPost,
        ioArgs: {
            form: formDomNode
        }
    });
    dialog.set("href", formDomNode.action);

    dojo.connect(dialog, 'onHide', dojo.hitch(dialog, function() {
        this.destroyRecursive();
    }));

    dialog.show();
```

DialogSimple is completely Dialog and dojox ContentPane mixed and ContentPane supports post as well as get. "href" must be set afterwards rather than as an initial parameter or else it doesn't work properly for some reason.

Doing a post to dojox ContentPane directly: (note that it only executes the javascript when it is placed on the actual page)

```
    var cp = new dojox.layout.ContentPane({
        ioMethod: dojo.xhrPost,
        ioArgs: {
            form: formDomNode
        }
    }, "dialogContent");
    //cp.placeAt("dialogContent");
    cp.set("href", formDomNode.action);
```